# Python3.6 and wanish issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the Wanish library in python and getting the following instead of the result expected.

```
>>> from wanish import Wanish
>>> wanish = Wanish()
>>> wanish.perform_url("http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-london-40269625")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wanish-0.6.3-py3.6.egg\wanish\__init__.py", line 167, in perform_url
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wanish-0.6.3-py3.6.egg\wanish\summarizer.py", line 55, in get_plain_text
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wanish-0.6.3-py3.6.egg\wanish\summarizer.py", line 91, in create_referat
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wanish-0.6.3-py3.6.egg\wanish\summarizer.py", line 68, in textrank
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wanish-0.6.3-py3.6.egg\wanish\langid.py", line 175, in classify
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wanish-0.6.3-py3.6.egg\wanish\langid.py", line 148, in instance2fv
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I have tried this using Python 3.6 and even with python 2.7

I came across the same issues.

Comment: so... trace it back?

Comment: I tried to trace it but could not understand what might be the problem.

Comment: Looks like a bugged distribution. Try uninstalling and installing a different, stable version.

Comment: Are you sure it's Python 3.6 compatible?

Comment: May be not compatible but it is 100% compatible with python 2.7, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you visit [pypi wanish page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wanish) you will see that it located only in Python 3.x categories:

> Programming Language :: Python
>
> Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
>
> Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
>
> Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5

It won't work in Python 2 because in code there is `from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin` line. But from docs:

> The `urlparse` module is renamed to `urllib.parse` in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

The offending line is this one* in `LanguageIdentifier.instance2fv()`:

```
arr = np.zeros((self.nb_numfeats,), dtype='uint32')
```

In `LanguageIdentifier.from_modelstring()`, the factory method used to instantiate this class, you can find this:

```
nb_numfeats = len(nb_ptc) / len(nb_pc)
```

In python3, division using the `/` operator always returns a float, where in python2 it returns an int if both operants are ints. So this is a bug.

The `langid.py` file seems to actually come from a different project, where this error [was fixed a while ago](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py/issues/46).

---

*I would normally link to the code directly, but someone decided to drop a ~2.4MB blob of base64 in the source file, so github doesn't allow linking.